# String manipulation returns right value when print statement is in, breaks when removed

Tags: c, string, pointers, printf

I have the following code to parse a URL:

```
char* getHost(char* url) {
char ret_s[strlen(url)];
    strcpy(ret_s, url);
    char* s = ret_s;
    char* finder = NULL;

    finder = strstr(s, "//");
    if (finder!=NULL) { // strip http://
        s = strstr(s, "//")+2;
    }
    finder = strstr(s, "/");
    if (finder!=NULL) {
        s = strtok(s, "/"); // strip /yadda yadda
    }

    printf("\nSanity Print: %s\n", s);
    return s; // return /sample.htm
}
```

Passing the function "http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/C/node19.html" with the print there returns:

```
Sanity Print: www.cs.cf.ac.uk
Host: www.cs.cf.ac.uk (outside the function)
```

but when the print is removed and I instead print outside the function, I get

```
Host: w
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Also,`char ret_s[strlen(url)];` --> `char ret_s[strlen(url)+1];`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`s` points into `char ret_s[strlen(url)];` which is an array with automatic storage duration. When you return from the function, the array storage is discarded and accessing it again invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: Would not have thought of that, I let it malloc some memory and that fixed my problem. Thanks!

Comment: @Scientaster Moreover, be careful you have an off-by-one overflow with `char ret_s[strlen(url)]; ... strcpy(ret_s, url);`. You need `strlen(url) + 1`.